# Set Greenshot default to 'Capture region' via cmd line or shortcut (ie. like snipping tool)

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, greenshot, snipping-tool

I like Greenshot alot but am very use to Snipping Tool behaviour of defaulting to 'capture region'.

I thought there would be a simple cmd line for doing this (ie. 'greenshot.exe /region') but alas there is no CLI for greenshot.

I like having an icon pinned to my taskbar for quick and easy region capture, like with snipping tool allows, however after capture snipping tool is lacking.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to start Greenshot with immediate region capture. However, there is an option to launch Greenshot on startup (which should be ticked by default if you have used the installer).

[image: Settings dialog: Launch Greenshot on startup]

With Greenshot already running in the background, you can quickly trigger a region capture using the <kbd>Prnt</kbd> key or the context menu of the systray icon.

Comment: Thanks. I had found as much. Still would love CLI :-/

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this, however a release of Greenshot 2.0 is upcoming and there are several open feature tickets requesting this functionality.

https://greenshot.atlassian.net/projects/FEATURE/issues/filter=allopenissues?filter=allopenissues&orderby=priority%20DESC&keyword=command%20line

Requesting / showing demand / donating may help the feature appear faster.